# How to add WPF UserControl to Avalonia Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, avaloniaui

I created a Avalonia Window.
I need to play a video but Avalonia hasn't supported MediaElement yet.  I want to use System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement.
Is it possible to add a Window Controls in Avalonia Window?

Comment: *"It has many similarities to WPF"* - from tag [tag:avaloniaui], doesn't means it can show something from wpf. Why do you think it is possible to use wpf controls in someone else multiplatform framework?

Comment: MediaElement (as everything in WPF) is not cross-platform. Even if Avalonia had support for hosting WPF controls there would be no point in using it, since it would make your app not cross-platform as well. And if you app is not cross-platform, you might as well use WPF instead.

There is AvaloniaAV project (https://github.com/jkoritzinsky/AvaloniaAV/), but it currently only supports Windows platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LibVLCSharp.Avalonia](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LibVLCSharp.Avalonia/)